# How to convert a PNG to a WebP in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, objective-c++

I'm trying to convert a PNG image in Webp in Swift, the only framework I got working is **OpenCV** through *Objective-c++*. 
 The problem is that if I resize the image by 512x512 (that's the resolution I need) it crashes:
[image]
If I resize the image (either with OpenCV either with Swift) to another resolution (ex 510x510) it doesn't crash.

The strange thing is that on the simulator it never crashes while on the iPhone XS it crashes 90% of the times. 
How can I convert a PNG to a Webp in Swift? 
Why is OpenCV crashing on the *imwrite* instruction if the Mat is 512x512?

**UPDATE**:

 OpenCV version: 3.4.2
I found out that this problem happens when the PNG image get processed before from the Core Graphics framework. I need to use it since I save a UIVIew as UIImage this way:

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
```

Comment: Could you, please create a [mcve] that reproduces this? (Post it as text, not an image) | What version of OpenCV?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using another framework to convert PNG to WebP: https://github.com/seanooi/iOS-WebP, had to create the wrapper to use it on swift but it works very good

My wrapper is very simple but does what I needed:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "WebPWrapper.h"
#import "UIImage+WebP.h"

@implementation WebPWrapper
-(NSData *)convertUIImageToWebp:(UIImage *)image :(int)quality {
    NSData *webPData = [UIImage imageToWebP:image quality:quality];
    return webPData;
}
@end
```

In **swift** I use it this way:

```
let webPData = WebPWrapper().convertUIImage(toWebp: image, 90)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21475418)

Comment: Just added the solution 

Comment: @Danny182 Hello, I tried this but not working properly. I mean it returns `nil` image when decode from `.webp` to png image from `Data`. Can you please share your example so it can help many of us. Struggling since a week, now you are the only hope!

Comment: For this need I used another library even if I’m sure the one that I used here (iOS-webp) does the same but you need to create the function in the wrapper for that need.   If you want you could check the library YYImage. I used that library to decode webp image to data

Comment: @Danny182 yeah it helped..Thanks :) Btw..why I get it resultant image with slightly blue shade on it? Any idea? did you face this?

Comment: Are you processing your image with any other framework? CoreImage or Accelerator? if not, try to @iRiziya

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4.0

pod both `'SDWebImage'` ( https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage ) AND `'SDWebImage/WebP'` ( https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageWebPCoder )

import `SDWebImage`

```
if let image_download = UIImage(data: data) {
   let photo:Data = image_download.sd_imageData(as: SDImageFormat.webP)!
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an "findWriterForTypeAndAlternateType:119: unsupported file format 'org.webmproject.webp" error when trying to do this

Answer (score 0):

For anyone just want to convert images into WEBP format:

First install: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageWebPCoder

```
import SDWebImageWebPCoder
...

let image = UIImage(...) // define the image    

let webpData = SDImageWebPCoder.shared.encodedData(with: image, format: .webP, options: nil)!

let webpImage = UIImage(data: webpData)!
```